# Relação histórico-linguística entre o verbo "haver" [existir] e os casos ergativo e absolutivo

Tags: linguística

Existe relação histórico-linguística entre o verbo "haver" [existir] e os casos [ergativo e absolutivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative%E2%80%93absolutive_language)?

> X existe. X há. Existe X. Há X.

As quatro são expressões intercambiáveis. X com o verbo *haver* se comporta como objeto quando poderia ser sujeito, pois 'haver' é impessoal em vez de intransitivo; ou seja, se 'haver' fosse intransitivo (por qualquer motivo),
'X' seria sujeito em vez de objeto.

No ergativo-absolutivo (casos indo-europeus), o argumento (sujeito) de um verbo intransitivo se comporta como objeto de um transitivo. O caso ergativo é utilizado para agentes de verbos transitivos, e o absolutivo para sujeitos de intransitivos e objetos de transitivos.

Portanto, o objeto de 'haver', podendo possivelmente ser sujeito em uma hipótese em que 'haver' é intransitivo, resguarda alguma relação com como o caso absolutivo relaciona sujeitos de intransitivos e objetos de transitivos?

Detalhes:

1. As línguas osco-úmbricas possuem casos morfológicos assim como latim
   (porém não descubri quais são esses casos), e um cognato para o
   *habeo* — origem de *haver*.
2. *Habeo* aparenta não dispor da regência para existir, o que pode implicar alguma alteração na palavra até concluir sua versão no
       ibero-ocidental.
3. *Haver* [existir] existe apenas em castelhano, português e galego. Em catalão, a tradução se faz "Hi [pronome] ha [verbo] X."; em
       italiano, "C'è [lá é] X.", igual ao inglês; em francês, "Il [ele] y
       [lá] a [tem] X."; em romeno "Există X.".

P.S.: ponderei postar em Linguistics, porém por ser um site em inglês julguei a pergunta específica demais e decidi postar aqui. Acredito que ficarei sem resposta e terei de contatar um linguista; nesse caso, alguém teria uma recomendação?

Comment: Se de fato ninguém responder aqui, talvez no ciberdúvidas você possa ter mais sorte. E talvez no blog [Diário de um Linguista](https://diariodeumlinguista.wordpress.com/quem-sou-eu-4/) possam te responder. Boa sorte.

Comment: (Uau, que boa pergunta! Das difíceis... : ) William, "X há" é válido no geral? Só consigo pensar em exemplos que precisam do contexto de uma pergunta... podias-me dar um exemplo?

Comment: @ANeves Soa estranho mas não conheço regra gramatical que invalide essa construção. De fato, mais comum em respostas.
— Há esperança?
— Esperança há!

Comment: Existe algum caso no qual haver ou existir não são intransitivos??

Comment: @Lambie 'Haver' nunca é intransitivo, não existe 'Ele há'. Haver pode ser impessoal (sem sujeito) ("Há [verbo] cavalos [objeto direto] no parque [adjunto adverbial de lugar]"),  ou transitivo (exemplo: "Eu hei de dormir mais cedo hoje"). Existir todavia é sempre intransitivo.

Comment: Outras línguas ibéricas também têm este uso de haver: o mirandês, o asturiano e o aragonês, por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Há línguas, como o latim (e, até onde eu saiba, todas as línguas indo-europeias), que têm um sistema de casos nominativo-acusativo. E há línguas, como o basco, que têm um sistema de casos ergativo-absolutivo (e há ainda línguas, como se pode ver pela tese que a @Maria Isabel Berrido Marchese indicou, que usam sistemas diferentes para cada tempo verbal). Sendo uma língua nominativo-acusativa para todos os tempos verbais, o Latim não tem caso ergativo nem caso absolutivo. Como o português é derivado do latim, o pouco que resta do nosso sistema de casos deriva do latim, e é, até onde ainda é reconhecível, do tipo acusativo-nominativo, não do tipo ergativo-absolutivo.

---

Qual a diferença entre os dois sistemas?

No sistema nominativo-acusativo, o caso **nominativo** é o caso do sujeito de todos os verbos, tanto transitivos quanto intransitivos:

> **Eu** abracei o João.
>
> **Eu** chorei.

E o **acusativo** é o caso dos objetos diretos dos verbos transitivos (os intransitivos, naturalmente, não têm objeto):

> O João **me** abraçou.

Nas línguas ergativo-absolutivas, o sujeito dos verbos transitivos é o **ergativo**, e o **absolutivo** é usado para os objetos dos verbos transitivos e para o sujeito dos intransitivos. Se o português fosse herdeiro de uma língua ergativo-absolutiva, o nosso uso seria assim:

> **Eu** abracei o João.
>
> **Me** chorei.

---

No caso dos verbos "haver" e "existir", porém, o que ocorre é um pouco diferente.

O verbo "existir" é um verbo intransitivo, como muitos outros. Ele admite um sujeito, e flexiona de acordo com ele:

> Existem muitas estrelas.
>
> Existe uma esperança.

Ele tem também uma característica menos comum, que é a de mais frequentemente vir antes do sujeito quando este é um substantivo comum (embora com sujeitos pronominais, ou nomes próprios, se comporte de forma mais ortodoxa):

> Existe uma falha na filosofia de Aristóteles.
>
> Eu existo, tu existes, ele existe.
>
> Maria Clara existe, João Pedro existe, Deus existe.

De qualquer forma, o caso que ele exige dos seus sujeitos é o mesmo caso que os verbos transitivos exigem dos seus - é portanto um nominativo, e não um ergativo.

Já o verbo "haver" (no sentido de "existir"; como verbo auxiliar, ou no sentido já arcaizante de "ter" ele é mais convencional) é uma coisa bastante rara em português: um verbo "impessoal", isto é, um verbo que, ao contrário dos intransitivos, admite objeto direto, mas não admite sujeito:

> Há uma esperança.
>
> Há muitas estrelas. (E não "hão muitas estrelas", porque as estrelas não são sujeito aqui.)

Infelizmente, na língua portuguesa só os pronomes têm caso, e o verbo "haver", no sentido de "existir", geralmente não admite pronomes como objeto, de forma que é difícil saber qual caso ele exige dos seus objetos:

> ?Há eu.
>
> ?Há tu.
>
> *Há-me.
>
> *Há-te.

(**Talvez** as duas primeiras construções sejam possíveis como respostas a uma pergunta do tipo "há alguém que...?), o que apontaria para outra anormalidade, um objeto que usa o caso do sujeito, mas não flexiona o verbo:

> Há alguém aqui que fale sânscrito fluentemente?
>
> -?**Há eu**.

(Com certeza esse é o caso de "ter" quando tem sentido de "existir": "Tem alguém que...? - Tem eu". Mas acredito que mesmo assim só seja admissível nos registros coloquial e popular - e aí há uma certa incompatibilidade entre esses registros e o uso de "haver" no sentido de "existir"...)

Por outro lado, segundo o @Artefacto, "há-o" e suas flexões, assim como pelo menos "as há" são construções aceitáveis em PT-PT. Sendo esse o caso, reforça-se o argumento: o verbo haver comporta-se como um verbo transitivo, admite um objeto, e o caso desse objeto é o acusativo. E o seu complemento é um objeto, e não um sujeito, por que não flexiona o verbo, que se mantém, "impessoalmente", sempre na terceira pessoa do singular.

Agora, talvez se possa argumentar que o verbo "haver" está perdendo sua "impersonalidade" e os seus objetos estão sendo reinterpretados como sujeitos; construções como

> *Haverão ocasiões de conflito; para isso servem os órgão judicantes.
>
> *Haviam dias em que tudo parecia perdido.

que são formalmente proibidas pela gramática normativa, vêm se tornando comuns no português coloquial brasileiro - e, às vezes, insinuam-se até mesmo em textos que se propõem a seguir a norma padrão. Se isso se generaliza e se torna aceitável no futuro, aí sim teremos uma situação que pode guardar alguma semelhança com o sistema ergativo-absolutivo: um verbo intransitivo, que tem um complemento que se comporta como sujeito (fazendo o verbo flexionar), mas que exige desse complemento o "caso oblíquo".

O problema é que cada um desses fenômenos abarca diferentes manifestações do verbo. A flexão do complemento de acordo com o verbo se dá exclusivamente com complementos não-pronominais, e quando o complemento é pronominal e podemos assim aferir que o caso exigido pelo verbo é oblíquo, a flexão nunca ocorre (pelo menos pelo que entendi dos comentários do @Artefacto; é "há-os" e "as há", nunca *"hão-nos" ou *"as hão". Não por acaso, creio, cada uma dessas construções ocorre de um lado diferente do oceano: *"haverão ocasiões" é inovação brasileira, "os há" é (inovação? arcaísmo? eruditismo?) lusitano.

---

Para encurtar conversa, num sistema ergativo-absolutivo, o verbo "existir", sendo intransitivo, exigiria do seu sujeito o mesmo caso dos objetos dos verbos transitivos diretos - o "caso absolutivo":

> Existo-me.
>
> Existes-te.
>
> Existe-lhe.

O que, evidentemente, não é o caso.

E o verbo haver, não sendo nem transitivo nem intransitivo, mas essa anomalia que é um "verbo impessoal", continuaria a ter um objeto direto, que, suponho, demandaria o "caso absolutivo", e não o "ergativo", que é reservado ao sujeito de verbos transitivos:

> Há-me.
>
> Há-te.

O que, não só evidente, mas também felizmente, não é o caso.

---

Portanto, a questão que você levanta não parece relacionada a uma possível sobrevivência de um sistema ergativo-absolutivo (que teria de ser uma sobrevivência de uma língua anterior ao latim: proto-itálico, ou proto-indo-europeu). Mas se esse fosse o caso, então o latim *habere* deveria poder ser utilizado no sentido de "existir", o que você diz não ocorrer. E esse tipo de construção, como você aponta, só existe em português, galego e castelhano, portanto o mais provável é que seja uma inovação introduzida a partir do romance ibérico (o catalão deriva do romance provençal, não do romance ibérico).

E, se é uma inovação, é improvável que vá no sentido do ergativo-absolutivo (a não ser que fosse um empréstimo sintático do basco, o qual, de fato, é uma língua ergativo-absolutiva). Muito mais plausivelmente, vem de alguma construção similar à francesa ("ele há muitas estrelas"), com queda do pronome (que é característica do romance ibérico; "sei falar francês" versus "je sais parler français").

Aliás, em português mesmo, é assim que interpretamos construções como

> Me confundi (ou, "confundi-me").

Entendemos isso como "Eu me confundi", com sujeito "oculto", não como um caso anômalo em que a forma oblíqua "me" funciona como sujeito.

Assim, a resposta para a sua pergunta é,

> Não, não há relação histórico-linguística entre o uso do verbo "haver" no sentido de "existir" e o sistema ergativo-absolutivo de casos".

---

(disclaimer: o "eu" de uma das frases acima com certeza não sou eu. Eu não falo sânscrito fluentemente - e nem não-fluentemente...)

Comment: De facto, não se pode dizer _há-me_, mas pode dizer-se _há-o_. Por exemplo: _não acredito em bruxas mas que as há, há_ / _eu non creo nas meigas, mais habelas hainas_ / _no creo en brujas, pero que las hay, las hay_. E o sujeito expletivo _ele_ também é usado com _haver_ nalguns dialetos.

Comment: Já agora, não tenho a certeza sobre a aceitabilidade de _há-me a mim_, mas em todo o caso parece-me muito melhor que _há eu_.

Comment: @Artefacto, acho que a regra geral é que, no padrão, "haver", no sentido de existir, não aceita objetos pronominais. "Há eu" talvez seja marginalmente aceitável no coloquial brasileiro, embora não no coloquial europeu. "Há-me a mim" é inaceitável em PT-BR, qualquer que seja o registro; em PT-PT, podes explicar melhor do que eu. E quanto "há-as" ou "as há", faço como com as bruxas: ainda que existam, não acredito nelas. Acho que "as há" pode ser talvez aceito no registro literário em PT-BR, mas a tradução usual é "que elas existem, existem". "Há-as", nem isso.

Comment: Em Portugal, _há-o_ e variantes são relativamente comuns. Por exemplo, procurando apenas "há-as" (sem considerar próclise e outro género/número do pronome) devolve 40 ocurrências no CETEMPúblico. De qualquer forma, a pergunta menciona tb galego e castelhano.

Answer (score 0):

> As línguas osco-úmbricas possuem casos morfológicos assim como latim (porém não descubri quais são esses casos), e um cognato para o habeo — origem de haver.

Os únicos documentos sobre a língua úmbria que descobri na internet são: [Umbrian language words & meanings](https://thevore.com/umbrian/) e [A grammar of Oscan and Umbrian : with a collection of inscriptions and a glossary](https://archive.org/details/grammarofoscanum00buckuoft/page/14)

O primeiro é uma simples lista de palavras, com as respectivas traduções e/ou cognatos em latim e indo-europeu, às vezes com indicações como "acc.", "loc.", "abl", que parecem ser abreviaturas dos nomes dos casos. Se assim é, então tudo indica que o úmbrio tinha um sistema de casos do tipo nominativo-acusativo, como o latim. Achei as abreviaturas que listo abaixo, na ordem em que aparecem, com a interpretação que me parece óbvia:

> abl.pl. (ablativo plural)
>
> acc.pl. (acusativo plural)
>
> loc.sg. (locativo singular)
>
> acc.sg. (acusativo singular)
>
> dat.sg. (dativo singular)
>
> gen.pl. (genitivo plural)
>
> gen. (genitivo)
>
> dat. (dativo)
>
> abl. (ablativo)

Assim, estariam presentes aí quatro dos seis casos do latim, ablativo, acusativo, dativo e genitivo - faltando o vocativo e o nominativo. Há muitos substantivos dados sem indicação de caso; me pergunto se esses não estarão no nominativo.

E há pelo menos um caso que já não existia no latim clássico, embora provavelmente existisse no latim arcaico, o locativo.

O outro documento é uma gramática completa (na medida do possível para uma língua da qual resta um *corpus* diminuto). Ele basicamente confirma o que já foi deduzido do outro: um sistema de seis casos, sendo os seis do latim menos o vocativo e mais o locativo (embora o uso dos casos não seja exatamente igual ao do latim).